# How parse JIRA logs using Grok?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, jira

My jira logs has syntax: ***10.5.204.7 1439x14430008x1 A193A1AA [15/Mar/2018:00:00:02 +0530] "GET /jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project='AT'%20OR%20***

Iam trying to parse it through grok filter:

grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IPV4:ip}" (?[0-9A-F]{8}) [%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\  }
  }

But it is not working. I only need to filter ipadress, id(A193A1AA) and datetime.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
grok{
            break_on_match => false         
            match => {"message" => "%{IP:clientIP} (?<Data>[A-Z\-a-z . /=?0-9\[\]:()%]+) (?<id>[A-Z\-a-z . /=?0-9\[\]:()%]+) \[%{HTTPDATE:logDate}\]"}
}
```

please note that the " " position should include all pattern

https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: if it worked , could you give me the answer is correct ? thanks